# Big forward slash in math

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I have an equation in from of

> a=VERYBIGSTUFF / VERYBIGSTUFF

And I would like to have a "verybig" forward slash in the middle of them. I don't like `\frac` mode, as I would like to have them left-to-right, not one above the other. I tried also changing the size of the "/" like `\text{\LARGE $/$}` but this gives a non centered slash, it goes upwards (as a different typography size would do, of course).

How can I insert that big forward slash?

Comment: Is `\bigg/` enough?

Comment: O.o @Manuel I wish all the problems could be solved as fast as you solved mine. Post your comment as an answer, as I didnt find a solution to this googling, so It may be interesting or future lost latex newbies as me.

Comment: Do you want the slash just lengthened to the proper size, or also thickened in line thickness?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is also possible to put the equation into the brackets and then use the \middle/ instead of the regular slash.

So, for example, this equation:

```latex
\int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} / \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y}
```

would turn into this one:

```latex
\left[ \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \middle/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right]
```

Or if you do not need any visible brackets, you may use the "fake" brackets instead:

```latex
\left. \int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \middle/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y} \right.
```

[image: Example of large slash in math]

Comment: Wow, I knew about `\left` and `\right`, but I somehow never heard about `\middle`. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
a=\textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} \Biggm/ \textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} 
\]

or (compare the spacing)

\[
a=\textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} \Bigg/ \textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} 
\]

In a real situation it would look nicer:

\Huge
\[
 a=\textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} \Biggm/ \textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} 
\]

or (compare the spacing)

\[
a=\textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} \Bigg/ \textrm{\Huge VERYBIGSTUFF} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I wouldn't use `\biggm` here. May be its space comes in handy, but it gives `/` relation spacing which might not be desired. I would use `\bigg` (or whatever size) and may be add manual space at wish.

Comment: What is the difference b/w the first and second pair of examples? I can't see any difference in the code but there is an obvious difference in the output.

Comment: @Kartik In the first pair slash acts as a binary operator, hence the skips around it are bigger.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a simple one-line solution, I always use just `\left.` - `\right/` pair:

```
\begin{equation}
    a = \left.VERYBIGSTUFF \right/ VERYBIGSTUFF
\end{equation}
```

Example:

```
\begin{equation}
    a = \left.\int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{x}{y} \right/ \int \limits_c^d \frac{x}{y}
\end{equation}
```

Output:

[image]

Very simple and efficient. Works well unless you have incredibly big stuff like in the answer of `Steven B. Segletes`

Comment: Great late answer. As you say, very simple also

Comment: @AnderBiguri Well, better late than never :) I was surprised to find this 2-year-old question still didn't have the simplest solution!

Answer (score 5):

The drawback of this solution is that the line is thickened, but the advantage is that it will work even if the equation gets "really really big".

Here. I vertically auto-stretch a `/` to make the tall slash of any required height, but add width if necessary so that the overall aspect ratio of the stretched glyph can not exceed 500% (i.e., 5:1).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\LargeExpression{\frac{~~\displaystyle\frac{x^2 +2x + 3}{g_x}~~}{\displaystyle\frac{x^3}{y+1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\stretchleftright[500]{.}{\LargeExpression}{/} 2
\]
\[
A \stretchleftright[500]{/}{\LargeExpression}{.}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the fabulous `\mathrule` you could make a solution that doesn't gets thicker.